# Significance level in hpgenselect procedure in SAS

Tags: sas, significance

I am building models with proc hpgenselect but I can't set significance level. In Docs I found out that parameter: *ALPHA= Specifies a global significance level*. However SAS still use default value of 0.05 building model (see on image below). 
 [image: Significance level]
I wanted to see which parameters will come to model over diffrent significance levels but now I can't do this. *&significance.* is a macro variable. My code:

```
%let significance = 0.15;

proc hpgenselect data=MySet ALPHA=&significance.;
model Y = &Var./ dist=nb ALPHA=&significance.;
id id;
selection method=STEPWISE(stop=SL) DETAILS=SUMMARY;
run;
```

Comment: What is your version of SAS/STAT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `SLS=&significance` on the `SELECTION` statement. I believe that controls the alpha for selection.  The `ALPHA=` on the `model` is for the confidence intervals produced, and `ALPHA=` on the `hpgenselect` also controls the confidence intervals.

```
proc hpgenselect data=MySet ALPHA=&significance.;
model Y = &Var./ dist=nb ALPHA=&significance.;
id id;
selection method=STEPWISE(stop=SL SLS=&significance) DETAILS=SUMMARY;
run;
```

That should give you want you want.

Comment: Thank you mate, that's exactly what I wanted! How did you know that? :)

Comment: @Roberto, I had to dig through the documentation.  There is definitely a learning curve to reading it (I used to write documentation for SAS, so I can navigate it fairly well).

Comment: I've some questions about this procedure. Do You know how it iterprets weights? In Stata and SAS i ve got different results, but without them I have pretty the same.Could you help me ?

Comment: Ask a new question and someone should be able to help.  Also try going through the documentation on the methodologies.